# How can I combine two strings and create sets by 4 characters, two coming from one string and other two from other string? c#

Tags: c#, string

I got stuck in creating an algorithm that creates sets of 4 characters from two strings, two characters from one string and two from other string.
Example:

- String one: `FIRSTNAME`
- String two: `LASTNAME`

and the result that I expect is to get `10` sets of `4` characters like this: `FILA, RSST, TNNA, AMME, EFLA` and so on until we get `10` combinations like this.

this is the code that I made

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Lastname");

        string lastname = Console.ReadLine();

        int i;

        var nchars = name.ToCharArray();
        var pchars = lastname.ToCharArray();

        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
            int ctr0;
            int ctr;
            int ctr2;

            for (ctr = 0, ctr2 = 1, ctr0 = 1; 
                 ctr < 10; 
                 ctr0++, ctr = ctr + 2, ctr2 = ctr2 + 2) {
              Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}",
                  ctr0,
                  nchars[ctr],
                  nchars[ctr2],
                  pchars[ctr],
                  pchars[ctr2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is good so far because I get

```
1FILA
2RSST
3TNNA
4AMME
```

but it stops when the string ends and instead of getting 10 combinations I **get only** `4`.. what can I do? 
Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: you are incrementing `ctr` by 2 in the `for` loop and your condition reads `ctr < 10` hence it gives you only 4 results.

Comment: What are the ten results you expect?

Comment: I'm getting an Index out of bounds error. I think you might need to set the length of each string (FIRSTNAME = 9, LASTNAME = 8). And in each loop do a check that you have not exceeded that length. When you do exceed that length you'll need to roll your ctr variables over to reset to the beginning of the string for the string that exceeded the length.

Comment: @OlivierRogier the ten results that I expect are FILA, RSST, TNNA , AMME, EFLA, IRST, STNA, NAME, MELA, FIST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or adding some Enumerable love.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Lastname");
        string lastname = Console.ReadLine();

        // set the number of required sets and size
        const int sets = 10;
        const int size = 2;

        // make both inputs long enough
        var input1 = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(name, (Math.Abs((sets * size) / name.Length) + 1)));
        var input2 = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(lastname, (Math.Abs((sets * size) / lastname.Length) + 1)));

        // enumerate the index so we can substring the inputs.    
        var results = Enumerable.Range(0, sets)
            .Select(x => $"{x + 1}{input1.Substring(x * size, size)}{input2.Substring(x * size, size)}");

        // optional write to console
        foreach(var result in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lovely. Thanks a lot. Exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Trying to rectify your alogrithm, I think this is what you should try:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name");
        string name = "FIRSTNAME";
        Console.WriteLine("Lastname");
        string lastname = "LASTNAME";
        int i;
        var nchars = name.ToCharArray();
        var pchars = lastname.ToCharArray();
        var ncharsCount = nchars.Length;
        var pcharsCount = pchars.Length;
        //for (i=0;i<=10;i++){
            int ctr0;
            int ctr;
            int ctr2;
            for (ctr = 0, ctr2 = 1, ctr0=1; ctr0 < 10 ;ctr0++, ctr++,ctr2++){
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", ctr0,nchars[ctr%ncharsCount],nchars[ctr2%ncharsCount],pchars[ctr%pcharsCount],pchars[ctr2%pcharsCount]);
            }
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Close but the output is not as expected

Answer (score 0):

Let's *split* the initial problem into several *easier* ones:

1. `CircularSubstring`, e.g. for `value = "12345", index = 4, length = 3` we get `"512"`
2. `MyGemerator` which generate `"FILA", "RSST"` etc.
3. Final output in the required format

**Code:**

```
private static String CircularSubstring(string value, int index, int length) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

  // + + value.Length) % value.Length - 
  // .Net can return negative remainder when we want it to be in [0..value.Length) 
  for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    sb.Append(value[((index + value.Length + i) % value.Length + value.Length) % value.Length]);

  return sb.ToString();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> MyGenerator(string left, string right, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; ; i += size) 
    yield return CircularSubstring(left, i, size) + CircularSubstring(right, i, size);
}
```

Then we are ready to generate a `report` in required format:

```
string one = "FIRSTNAME";
string two = "LASTNAME";

int size = 2;  // chunks of size 2 from each (one, two) strings
int take = 10; // 10 chunks to generate

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyGenerator(one, two, size)
  .Take(take)
  .Select((item, index) => $"{index + 1}{item}")
);

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
1FILA
2RSST
3TNNA
4AMME
5EFLA
6IRST
7STNA
8NAME
9MELA
10FIST
```

**More demo:**

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyGenerator("Stack", "Overflow", 3)
  .Take(12)
  .Select((item, index) => $"{index + 1,2}. {item}")
));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 1. StaOve
 2. ckSrfl
 3. tacowO
 4. kStver
 5. ackflo
 6. StawOv
 7. ckSerf
 8. taclow
 9. kStOve
10. ackrfl
11. StaowO
12. ckSver
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful and actually worked but I wanted to maintain it as simple as possible.